# Python. Escribir una lista de listas con for

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

Buen día, tengo un problema que no he podido resolver y agradecería si me orientan.

Tengo una colección de listas con nombres similares.
(Aclaro que las listas se generaron, no se obtuvieron de una base de datos. Al final muestro el código con el que generé las listas)

Pero para fines prácticos ejemplificaré lo que tengo con un caso simple. Tengo las siguientes listas:

```
lista_1 = ['EUA', 'México', 'China']
lista_2 = ['Brazil', 'Colombia', 'España']
```

Lo que quiero generar es una lista con los nombres de las listas anteriores, algo así

```
listas = [lista_1, lista_2]
```

O en su caso algo como

```
listas = [['EUA', 'México', 'China'], ['Brazil', 'Colombia', 'España']]
```

Pero no he encontrado cómo. He probado con este código

```
listas = ['lista_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
```

Pero la salida me la da como si en la lista fueran strings

```
['lista_1', 'lista_2']
```

Y yo necesito que aparezca sin las comillas como

```
listas = [lista_1, lista_2]
```

He probado con f-strings, con strip() para quitar las comillas, tratando de hacer un ciclo for con append() y extend() pero realmente no logro hacer lo que quiero.

Aclaro que el código que muestro es un ejemplo, porque en verdad tengo 296 listas con varios valores. Aquí muestro el código que me permitió generar mis listas, no sé si sea de utilidad.

El DF que usé tenía 2 columnas, una con el nombre de un curso y la otra en los países en que se imparte, lo que yo hice fue generar listas con el nombre del curso y los países donde se imparte

```
for i in range(0, len(data['curso'].unique())):
    exec("data_{} = data[data['curso']==data['curso'].unique()[i]]".format(i))
    exec("lista_{} = list(data['curso'].unique()[i])".format(i))
    exec("lista_{} = ''.join(lista_{})".format(i,i))
    exec("lista_{} = [lista_{}]".format(i,i))
    exec("lista_{}.extend(list(set(data_{}['paises'])))".format(i, i))
```

Comment: Puede que te sirva usar [`locals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796264/what-does-pythons-locals-do). Aunque si tienes que recurrir a esto, tu problema es mas de diseño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es buena práctica crear variables del estilo `data_0`, `data_1`, `data_2`, `data_3`, etc... y menos si al final quieres juntarlas en una sola lista. Estas variables que has creado deberían ser, ya "desde que nacen", elementos de otra lista, y por tanto llamarse `datas[0]`, `datas[1]`, `datas[2]`, etc. (análogamente para las variables `lista_0`, etc.)

También es mala práctica usar `exec()` o `eval()` para ejecutar código en cadenas, aunque esto está relacionado con lo antes dicho, ya que si quieres crear mediante un bucle una serie de variables como has hecho tú, no queda otra que utilizar un truco del estilo `exec()`, pero si por el contrario creas las variables directamente como elementos de otra lista, no necesitarás andar con "trucos raros".

Lo que propongo que es que el bucle que crea las variables sea por tanto directamente el siguiente:

```
datas = []    # Todas tus variables data_0, data_1, etc. son ahora esta
listas = []   # Lo mismo para tus variables lista_0, lista_1, etc.

for i in range(0, len(data['curso'].unique())):
    data_aux = data[data['curso']==data['curso'].unique()[i]]
    lista_aux = list(data['curso'].unique()[i])
    lista_aux = [''.join(lista_aux)]
    lista_aux.extend(list(set(data_aux['paises'])))
    datas.append(data_aux)
    listas.append(lista_aux)
```

**Nota**. No he entrado a tratar de comprender qué pretendes hacer con ese código, probablemente se pueda simplificar también. Me he limitado a copiar lo mismo que hacías, pero sobre una variable `data_aux` y otra `lista_aux`, en vez de `data_0`, `lista_0`, etc. Una vez creadas esas listas auxiliares, las meto en las listas generales.

De este modo, al final, en `datas[0]` tendrás lo que antes tenías en tu `data_0`, y en `listas[0]` lo que antes era `lista_0`, etc.

El tenerlo todo en una lista general te permitirá iterar más fácilmente por sus elementos, en lugar de tener que andar iterando por los nombres de variables terminados en `_i`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía esta parte de las buenas "buenas prácticas" relacionadas a los bucles, comenzaré a aplicarlas juntos con las demás que he aprendido.

Y tu solución me sirvió, era justo lo que necesitaba. Nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buscas algo como esto?:

```
listas = []
listas.append(lista_1)
listas.append(lista_2)
print(listas)


output:
[['EUA', 'México', 'China'], ['Brazil', 'Colombia', 'España']]
```

Comment: Sí, pero con 296 listas, por lo que no le sirve hacerlo "a mano", sino mediante un bucle.

Comment: Efectivamente, eso busco, pero como comenta @abulafia quisiera hacerlo mediante un bucle. No obstante, ya compartieron una solución que me sirvió.